# Нужно ли разделять запятыми прилагательные «интересный» и «новый»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, однородные-неоднородные-определения

С одной стороны, эти прилагательные кажутся неоднородными, а следовательно, должны писаться без запятой.

Однако поиск по [Национальному корпусу русского языка](https://ruscorpora.ru/) всё-таки даёт примеры, где запятая стоит:

> Зрители с любопытством и восторгом теснились взглянуть на танцующих
> польку ― танец **интересный, новый**, модный, круживший всем головы.
>
> *[[Ф. М. Достоевский. Двойник (1846)]](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9)*

> ― Что я тебе скажу? Тема **интересная, новая**. Ее серьезно никто не разрабатывал.
>
> *[[В. И. Максимов. Дневник научного сотрудника (2003)]](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F)*

Может быть, при одних условиях запятая ставится, а при других нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Однородные и неоднородные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98) (справочник Розенталя):

> Согласованные определения являются однородными:
> <...>
> 8) если стоят **после** определяемого существительного (в этом положении каждое из определений непосредственно связано с существительным и имеет одинаковую смысловую самостоятельность): *Я видел женщину **молодую, прекрасную, добрую, интеллигентную, обаятельную*** (Ч.)...

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

1. Определения стоят **перед** определяемым словом (запятой нет):

**Интересное новое** *направление* ― молекулярные провода с изоляцией. [В. А. Тартаковский, С. М. Алдошин. Химия в XXI веке. Взгляд в будущее (2008) // «Вестник РАН», 2009]

Он вернулся к нам и работает у Лаврова на более скромной должности. Зато по **интересной новой** *теме*. [Б. Е. Черток. Ракеты и люди (1999)]

...это очень **интересный новый** *вид* нового рода рыб девонского периода. [С. В. Обручев. В неизведанные края. Путешествия на Север 1917-1930 гг. (1954)]

2. Определения стоят **после** определяемого слова (запятая есть):

Я когда вижу *что-то* **интересное, новое**, сразу думаю, а где это применить можно? [Евгений Коваленко. Коллекционер! // «Пятое измерение», 2002]

Смотришь программу ― *она* такая **интересная, новая**. [Мария Варденга. Сати Спивакова. Соло второй скрипки (2002) // «Домовой», 04.01.2002]

...рассказывала бы *что-нибудь* **интересное, новое**, не имеющее отношения ни к любви, ни к счастью...  [А. П. Чехов. У знакомых (1898)]

P. S. Такая пунктуация соответствует интонации. При постпозиции определяемого слова логическое ударение падает на него, а между определениями нет паузы. В обратном случае определения произносятся с перечислительной интонацией.
P. P. S. Не исключена постановка запятой, когда эти определения
«объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.)».

Сегодня я чувствую себя совершенно отдохнувшим и могу даже вновь ехать за сотни верст, но лишь при одном условии: в самое **интересное, новое** *место*... [П. К. Козлов. Географический дневник Тибетской экспедиции 1923-1926 гг. №5 (1926)]

В этом случае между определениями есть пауза.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ. По постпозиции понятно, но по P. P. S. и последнему примеру — не совсем. По какой именно причине стоит запятая в последнем примере? Одинаковое впечатление? Как понять в таком случае, что автор хотел сказать запятой. То правило, что в P. P. S., есть в каком-то справочнике с примерами.

Comment: @Eagle Об этом говорится в том же параграфе Розенталя,  пункт 1. 3).  В примерах, аналогичных последнему, может быть причинная связь: почему интересный? потому что новый. Ну и общее впечатление, конечно. Вообще, эта тема -- одна из самых запутанных, поэтому и интересных :))  Одни и те же определения могут быть как однородными, так и неоднородными. Немаловажную роль играет смысловая нагрузка, вкладываемая автором.

Comment: Да, очень интересно. Я столкнулся с этим, когда читал книгу и там было написано (не помню точно, но как-то так): _«Не думаете ли вы, что это открывает интересную, новую перспективу»_. И я не мог понять: зачем там запятая, может ошибка. А получается, что имеется ввиду, что перспектива «интересная и новая» с точки зрения производимого впечатления.

 Ответ принял. Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: @Eagle  Тоже спасибо!